# How to debug dll called through mex (psychtoolbox)?

Tags: c, matlab, debugging, mex, psychtoolbox

My situation is I am trying to debug my dll (written in c) which is get called by another c code which is wrapped into a mex file. Is there a way to do it? Thanks.

Comment: what OS/platform are you on?

Answer (score 1):

1. Debuggers can attach to process (http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/debugging-c-c-language-mex-files.html).
2. Use `printf` and write tests. I recommend you this because good logging is usually much more useful.